Determining the Equation of a Parabola in a Three-Dimensional Plane
I have a plane with three points: P1 (x1, y1, z1), P2 (x2, y2, z2) and P3(x3, y3, z3). These points represent a parabola where P3 is the vertex and the other two points are the ends of the parabola. The parabola is an arc on the plane that contains all these points, not a paraboloid, so the x, y, and z coordinates change as we move from one point to another.
We also know the distance between P1P2 Now, I want to find the equation of the parabola that represents these points. How should I solve this? What are the different ways to begin with this problem?

If you take $P_3M$ as $y$-axis and the tangent at $P_3$ as $x$ axis ($M$ is the midpoint of $P_1P_2$) then the equation of the parabola is $y=ax^2$, with $a=P_3M/P_1M^2$.

P1,P2,P3 are all known. All the values of the coordinates that I have mentioned here are known just need to find the equation of the parabola.

"The equation of the parabola" using which coordinates? If you want to use ad-hoc coordinates on the plane, then see my comment above. If you want to use the given 3D coordinates, then a parabola can be represented either as a couple of cartesian equations or as a triple of parametric equations. Which one do you need?

I would be so pleased if you give me using both the methods such that i would could the one that suits me the best in terms of understanding.

I don't understand why you say : "We also know the distance between $P_1P_2$ and the distance between the midpoint of $[P_1P_2]$ and $P_3$." : you know them beforehand because you know the coordinates of points $P_k$...

For the parametric equations, see the given answer. If you want the cartesian equations, project the three points on plane $xy$ and find the equation of the parabola in that plane, to be combined with the equation of plane $P_1P_2P_3$.

Preliminary remarks :

I will use indifferently the names "point" and "vector", assuming that all vectors have their origin... at the origin.

I situate my analysis in the general case, setting apart particular cases (linear systems with zero determinant for example...).

The method I propose is in the spirit "proof-of-concept" giving a longer solution for solving the probem "by  hand" (compared to the other answer) but not longer if "CAS"-assisted (CAS= Computer Algebra System).


Here is another totally different way to solve the issue. Its advantage is to give a clear view over the degrees of freedom we have.
The idea is to consider the looked-for parabola as the intersection of a cone and a plane parallel to one of its generatrices.
Let $P$ be the plane defined by points $P_k$ with equation
$$n_1x+n_2y+n_3z=k\tag{1}$$
Let $N(n_1,n_2,n_3)$ be the normal vector to this plane.
(of course, $n_1,n_2,n_3,k$ can be expressed as functions of the coordinates of the $P_k$s).
Let us denote by
$$M(m_1,m_2,m_3)\tag{2}$$
a unit vector orthogonal to $N$ (one degree of freedom), i.e., verifying
$$m_1n_1+m_2n_2+m_3n_3=0 \tag{3}$$
The equation of a general cone $C$ with apex at the origin is:
$$ax^2+by^2+cz^2+dxy+exz+fyz=0 \tag{4}$$
where we may assume WLOG, by homogeneity, that $a=1$.
Constraining (1) to be verified for the 3 points $P_k$ and for point $M$ gives a system of 4 linear equations with five unknowns $b,c,d,e,f$. We know that it suffices in this case to attribute a random value to one of the unknowns, for example $b=0$.
It remains now to describe in a parametrical way the curve which is the intersection of the plane $P$ and the cone $C$ with resp. equations (1) and (4). This is a classical issue that I can detail "on demand".
